# Cannot display set of uimages in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

```
  @implementation StudyViewController


      - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
//[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

...
Basically I receive the responseobject via afnetworking.
Then store the data in a globally defined nsmutable array called arData

```
                ............
                ...........

            [manager POST:studysearchUrl parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

    [Global sharedGlobal].arrData = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

}

```
     #pragma collection view methods


-      (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

return 1;
    }

     -(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

   {
   return [[[Global sharedGlobal]arrData] count];


  }
 -(UICollectionView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"StudyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then the nsmutable object indexes are stored as dictionary to be accessed while creating the image path. 
I needed to extract 3 sets of data(firstUID, second, third) from this nsmutable array which will be passed on to NSURL to construct the image url path as shown below.
The rest of the parameters (hyperText, UrlKey, portNumber, seperator) are passed via nsdictionary(not shown here).

```
           UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
           NSDictionary *dictionary = [Global sharedGlobal].arrData[indexPath.row];


          img.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@?parametersintheWebServer&firstID=%@&secondID=%@&thirdID=%@",hyperText, UrlKey, portNumber, seperator, [Global sharedGlobal].arrData[indexPath.row] [@"firstUID"],[Global sharedGlobal].arrData[indexPath.row][@"secondUID"],[Global sharedGlobal].arrData[indexPath.row][@"thirdUID"]]];









      return cell;


    }


     - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

     }
     @end
```

1- I cannot seem to get the NSLOG output anything in the console inside

```
           -(UICollectionView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

2- I cannot display any image even though I know the parameters received from the web service is correct (& I can NSLOG them without any issue when the viewdidload.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Checked your shared controller exists?

Comment: arrData nsmutable is defined in Global.h &It exists inside this view controllerStudyViewController

Answer (score 1):

You should first be seeing calls to `numberOfItemsInSection`. If you can set a breakpoint in there (or NSLog) and the see count for `[[[Global sharedGlobal]arrData] count]` is not greater than 0 then this may help trouble shoot. If it's not hitting that delegate call back maybe the delegates are not set up correctly for the collectionview.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long) [[[Global sharedGlobal]arrData] count]);
It is saying the code will never be executed?

Comment: I can actually see the count = 5. Still cannot get the image. 
In my scenerio, how can I set the delegates and data source? Bit confused with this one. Do I need to set the delegate and datasource to be itself? Thank you

Comment: Where are you putting `NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long) [[[Global sharedGlobal]arrData] count])` when you see that it will never be executed.

Comment: Resolved the issue. Set the delegate to itself. Silly me!. However, I got poor image scrolling issue at the moment.